# Trouble subsetting array by row in R

Tags: r, subset

I have an array of data and I am trying to subset only data from the states of OR and WA. I am trying to use the row STATE, and select any with the abbreviation OR and WA. When I run the script I get

```
Error in dat_trans[dat_trans, "STATE" == "OR", ] : 
incorrect number of dimensions
```

This is the data I'm working with:

```
dat_trans <- structure(c(
  "10263500", "   59.46390", "34.42083", "-117.8395", "CA", "old", NA,
  "10281800", "   31.38300", "36.77854", "-118.2645", "WA", "new", NA,
  "14037500", "   18.23760", "44.34155", "-118.6566", "OR", "new", NA
), .Dim = c(7L, 249L), .Dimnames = list(c("STAT_ID", 
"DRAIN_AREA", "LAT", "LON", "STATE", "STUDY", "HUC_BASIN"), NULL))
```

Then this is the script that I've attempted to subset the data with

```
csv_file_name=filelist[1]
dat=read.csv(csv_file_name,header=TRUE,sep=",")
dat_trans=t(dat)

summer_storm_matrix=array() 
    for (tt in 1:ncol(dat_trans)){
      storm_gaugedata=dat_trans[dat_trans,'STATE'=='OR',tt]
      summer_storm_matrix=cbind(summer_storm_matrix,storm_gaugedata)
    }
```

Comment: Images of data are marginally useful, it's much more helpful to provide actual data. The best two methods for this are pasting the output from `dput(head(x))` and making the data by hand with `data.frame` or `matrix`. Looking at your code, it appears that this is actually a `data.frame`, not an `array` or `matrix`. In that case, the only time a third "dimension" can be used in `\`[.data.frame\`` is when you don't want it to automatically reduce to vectors with the `drop=` argument, such as `mtcars[1,1]` versus `mtcars[1,1,drop=FALSE]`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, and sorry about that! If the data is rather large would I want to paste the entire dataset or not? Oh so this a data.frame, and not an array. Would it be recommended to convert the data into an array, so that it can be sorted by STATE?

Comment: You should not consider "sortability" when deciding `data.frame`-vs-`array`, consider primarily (1) the structure of the data, and (2) the tools you'll be using on the data. You should rarely post "all your data", instead a representative sample; this might be just the top 10 rows of it (e.g., the `head` of `dput(head(x))`); a random sample if the top 10 are under-variant; or very specific sample data, either "cherry-picked" from the real or completely made-up.

Comment: Pasting data or code like that in a comment rarely works, and in this case it is incomplete (it starts in the middle). Please always edit your question and put added data, code, and clarifications directly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors:

```
dat_trans[dat_trans, "STATE" == "OR", ]
          ^^^^^^^^^  ^     ^
```

1. Don't do `dat_trans[dat_trans...`, repeating the df name inside the indices doesn't make sense.
2. Don't quote the column "STATE", that makes it a string, not a column name. You wanted `STATE` column, or rather `dat_trans$STATE`

Solution:

```
dat_trans[dat_trans$STATE == "OR", ]

dat_trans[dat_trans$STATE == "OR", tt]
```

or if you use dplyr/tidyverse:

```
dat_trans %>% filter(STATE == "OR")
```